# How to map an arraylist in one line in java or kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

How to write the following code in one line in the function argument (in `Kotlin` or `Java`)?

```
/* list: ArrayList<String>, map: Map<String, String> */
val newList = ArrayList<String>()
for (item in list) newList.add(map[item])
someFun(newList)
```

I expect something like this:

```
someFun(/* code */)
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question). Answer: yes, you can. Just write it in java and then remove all breaks. What is the purpose of cramping it all into one line?

Comment: Using lambdas in Java 8+ it would probably be something like `someFun( list.stream().map(i -> map.get(i)).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()))`

Comment: @Turing85 I am learning Java/Kotlin and I was curious if I could use something like `list.forEach { /* use map */ }` and do it without using any new list.

Comment: "do it without using any new list" - if `someFun()` would be able to operate on each item independently you could use a stream to map the list elements to map values and then call the function on each of them - like my comment above just with `forEach(someFun)` instead of collecting the elements into a list first.

Comment: @Thomas `someFun()` can't operate on each item for my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is for Kotlin:

```
someFun(list.mapNotNull { map[it] })
```